# pubsub.projects.subscriptions.pull fails with INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-apis-explorer

I am trying Google Cloud API Explorer for

**Services > Cloud Pub/Sub API v1 > pubsub.projects.subscriptions.pull**

> Request
>
> POST
>   https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/mimic-integration-10-2019/subscriptions/telemetry:pull?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
>
> { }

and it fails with

> Response
>
> 400 Bad Request
>
> - Show headers -
>
> {  "error": {   "code": 400,   "message": "You have passed an invalid
>   argument to the service (argument=max_messages).",   "status":
>   "INVALID_ARGUMENT"  } }

What am I doing wrong? Other calls like **Services > Cloud Pub/Sub API v1 > pubsub.projects.subscriptions.list** work fine.

Comment: Authorization Scopes

Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
Do you have the correct OAuth scopes? Where do you get {YOUR_API_KEY} from?

Comment: As I indicated, other calls work. So, it's not an authentication problem.

Comment: I just looked at the API more closely, and there are some hidden arguments. Closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at the API

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull

more closely, and there are 2 hidden arguments. Would be nice if the explorer
did not hide them.

Works, once I provide the arguments:

> Request
>
> POST
>   https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/mimic-integration-10-2019/subscriptions/telemetry:pull?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
>
> {  "returnImmediately": true,  "maxMessages": 10 }
>
> Response
>
> 200 OK
>
> - Show headers -
>
> {  "receivedMessages": [   {    "ackId":
>   "WBFOBCEhPjA-RVNEUAYWLF1GSFE3GQhoUQ5PXiM_NSAoRRULUxNRXHUCRRBsVTN1B1ENGXN7NSY7UhsCBUcBdF9RGx9ZXH5KAFkEGHZ7ZXNiXBIACkNWVp_9-5a3oQ9vPGm409OgVFXLkN0hZhs9XBJLLD5-PTNFQV5AEkw2BkRJUytDCyo",
>   "message": {
>       "data": "eyJzbiI6IjIwOjE5OkFCOkY0OjI3OjFCIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJhY2MiOnsieCI6MjYsInkiOjMyLCJ6IjoxMDEyLCJ1bml0IjoibUcifSwiZ3lybyI6eyJ4IjoxMjIwLCJ5IjotNjgzNSwieiI6LTIzMTksInVuaXQiOiJtZGVnL3MifSwibWFnIjp7IngiOjQwLCJ5IjoxLCJ6IjotNCwidW5pdCI6InVUIn0sImxpZ2h0Ijp7InZhbHVlIjoxMzU1NywidW5pdCI6Im1MdXgifSwidGVtcCI6eyJ2YWx1ZSI6NTAwMDAsInVuaXQiOiJtQ2Vsc2l1cyJ9LCJwcmVzc3VyZSI6eyJ2YWx1ZSI6OTg4OTcsInVuaXQiOiJQYXNjYWwifSwiaHVtaWRpdHkiOnsidmFsdWUiOjM5LCJ1bml0IjoiJXJoIn19fQ==",
>       "attributes": {
>        "projectId": "mimic-integration-10-2019",
>        "deviceId": "mimic1",
>        "deviceNumId": "2683064391811245",
>        "deviceRegistryId": "mimic-registry",
>        "deviceRegistryLocation": "us-central1",
>        "subFolder": ""
>       },
>       "messageId": "789146468611865",
>       "publishTime": "2019-10-14T13:49:47.862Z"    }   }  ] }